# getting issue on Landscape mode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, layout

[image]
Please help I'm getting the keyboard issue. I'm getting the keyboard in Landscape mode but I have set the automation off for that view controller.

Comment: Please share how u set your automation off.

Comment: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` in the .plist file of your app.

This will make your `UIViewControllers` the ability to decide his own orientation.